# python loop breaks on special chars in django template

Tags: python, django, encoding

So I am working with django and an external List of names and values. With a custom template tag I am trying to display some values in my html template.

Here is a example of what the list could look like:

names.txt

```
hello 4343.5
bye 43233.4
Hëllo 554.3
whatever 4343.8
```

My template tag looks like this (simplified names of variables):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='operation_name')
def operation_name(member):
    with open('/pathtofile/member.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if member.member_name in line:
                number = float(line.split()[1])
                if number is not member.member_number:
                    member.member_number = number
                    member.save()
                return member.member_number
    return 'Not in List'
```

It works fine for entries without specials char. But it stops when a name in member.member_names has special chars. So if member.member_names would be Hëllo the entire script just stops. I can't return anything. This is driving me crazy. Even the names without special chars won't be displayed after any name with special chars occurred.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So this did the trick:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

But I don't know if this is a good solution.

Comment: What is this code doing in a template filter? Why would creating member objects from a file be the responsibility of display logic?

Comment: I am new to django. So maybe it makes no sense. I just want to check if the number in the text file differs from the entry in the database (the text files is updated daily) and if so i want to display the new value. It works as intended for normal names.

Comment: Do you want to ignore the special characters while comparing?

Comment: I can't even return member.member_name if it has special chars in it. The loop just breaks. So I guess it's the comparing failing. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you try to compare both to unicode:-

```
if (member.member_name).decode('latin1') in (line).decode('latin1'):
    number = float(line.split()[1])
    if number is not member.member_number:
        member.member_number = number
        member.save()
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately it results in the same behavior.

Comment: Do you want to that both strings that is Hëllo and Hello should be different?

Comment: Every name in the text file is in member but not every member is in the text file. I want to compare the names of the member object with the names in the text file. If the member name is in the text file, the script shall update the member and return the member.member_number which is displayed in the html template.

Comment: Thanks that at least gives me an error:
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xeb' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)